# Select all element-item with number greater than 50

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are many divs with `class="element-item"`. I want to select all the divs with the class `.element-item` with `class="number"` which is greater than 50 using jQuery.

```
<div class="element-item one " data-category="one">
    <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
    <p class="number">30</p>
    <p class="weight">200.59</p>
</div>
<div class="element-item two " data-category="two">
    <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
    <p class="number">60</p>
    <p class="weight">200.59</p>
</div>
<div class="element-item two " data-category="three">
    <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
    <p class="number">80</p>
    <p class="weight">200.59</p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use jquery each() function.

for ur case :

```
$(".element-item").each(function(){
     if(parseInt($(this).find(".number").html()) > 50){
          // This is .element-item div with number greater Than 50!
          // Try to alert its name
          alert($(this).find(".name").html());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.filter()` to filter the divs with the `value > 50`

```js
var divs = $('.element-item .number').filter(function(){
  return parseInt($(this).text()) > 50;
});

//add a specail class
divs.each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('special') 
});

console.log(divs.length);
```

```css
.special {
 background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element-item one " data-category="one">
  <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
  <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
  <p class="number">30</p>
  <p class="weight">200.59</p>
</div>
<div class="element-item two " data-category="two">
  <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
  <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
  <p class="number">60</p>
  <p class="weight">200.59</p>
</div>
<div class="element-item two " data-category="three">
  <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
  <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
  <p class="number">80</p>
  <p class="weight">200.59</p>
</div>
```